# Error bounds for a Romberg-style improvement of a non-linear approximation

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory, upper-bounds

I have a (possibly non-linear) functional $F$, which I want to numerically approximate by a (typically non-linear) $\widehat{F}_h$. For a suitable class of functions, I have asymptotic error behaviour
$$
\widehat{F}_h(f)=F(f)+c_2(f)h^2+c_4(f)h^4+\ldots
$$
and error bounds
$$
|\widehat{F}_h(f)-F(f)|\le Ch^2 \|G(f)\|_\infty
$$
where $G$ is a non-linear function that vanishes on a two-parameter family of functions on which $\widehat{F}_h$ is exact.

Now the asymptotic behaviour suggests considering a Romberg-style improvement
$$
\widetilde{F}_h(f) = \frac{4}{3}\widehat{F}_{\frac{h}{2}}(f)-\frac{1}{3}\widehat{F}_h(f)
$$
in which the leading error terms cancel, leaving $O(h^4)$ errors. However, I'm struggling to come up with any useful bounds on the error of $\widetilde{F}_h$. It is clear that $\widetilde{F}_h$ is exact on the family of functions on which $\widehat{F}_h$ is exact. But working with this naively only gives an $O(h^2)$ error bound since the subtraction in the definition of $\widetilde{F}_h$ turns into an addition in a triangle inequality, although the leading error should be $O(h^4)$. Digging into the details of $\widehat{F}_h$ that I skip here does not seem to help either, since there is always some $O(h^2)$ term that cannot be estimated away.

So here is my question: is there anything known generically about higher-order error bounds for Romberg-style improvements of approximations? All the references I could find on related error bounds were quite specific to the case where the functions on which the method is exact were polynomials. Are there more generic results, or is the situation quite hopeless without more specific features of $\widehat{F}_h$?